# Javascript class hierarchy (Is there such a thing?)

Tags: javascript

Coming from a .net background, I want to refactor my html/js application.

I am moving functions to a seperate js file.

How do I (can I) structure my functions in a class hierarchy?

```
myAppFunctions.ui

  Function A

myAppFunctions.db

  Function B

myApFunctions.math

  Function C
```

---

I would like to add a js link to my page, and call them using, I.e. myAppFunctions.math.C

Also, how do I return values to my top level calling code?

I am not looking for inheritance, instantiating objects etc at this time. I just need a good way to structure my code so it makes sense.

Thanks

Comment: There is no such thing as class-heirarchy in JavaScript, but you can achieve great engineering patterns here too... If you really want to understand and have time to invest in JavaScript then read this -> http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh , thanks for the tip. I am however looking for the short version on this one :-) Js is not my main environment, and in time, I will make the effort to master it. For now, I am learning as I go, to see where it takes me. I am not looking for inheritance, etc at this time. I just need a good way to structure my code so it makes sense.

Comment: You are looking for a *module* hierarchy or *namespaces*, the term "class hierarchy" implies inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you just want to namespace things, so use an object.

```js
var myAppFunctions = {};

myAppFunctions.ui = {
    a : function () { console.log("a"); } 
};

myAppFunctions.db= {
    b : function () { console.log("b"); } 
};

myAppFunctions.math= {
    double : function(num) { return num * 2; },
    half: function (num) { return num / 2; }      
};

console.log( myAppFunctions.math.double(3) );
```

Comment: Thanks, how do I add a_1 to .ui? My js editor complains when I just wire it in below a ...? Lets say I want ui.x and ui.y functions inside ui?

Comment: It is object notation so you need to add a comma.

Comment: Regarding multiple name spaces and functions, Re, performance. Since scripts are "loaded", it seems to make sense to split different namespaces into different physical files, and only linking those you are going to use in the current page?

Comment: @LouisvanTonder: Yes, although you need to consider that loading one large file is faster than loading many small files. If you have modules that are really only seldomly used, it makes sense to load those extra.

Comment: Thanks, I am working on a mobile/web app, hence I want to make it as "light" as possible. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Technically a build could make it light as possible by combining the multiple files and minimizing them. That is how I work with my widgets. Either way it is the same idea.

Comment: Sorry, one more thing. Can you please indicate in your answer how one would return a value from the various nested functions? I am trying to call a nested function and have it return true/false, but my calling code seems to be equated to the function itself, not its return.

Comment: I am returning a value from double and half...I am not sure what your issue is. Can you show a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of what your problem is?

Comment: It seems I had my calling order wrong... I got it working with the fiddle now... let me try my actual code

Comment: `var onDevice = planB.ops.isThisOnDevice;`  <-- that is not calling the function, that is just assigning a reference to the function. It should have `()` so the function executes `var onDevice = planB.ops.isThisOnDevice();`

Comment: Haha, alright then. N00b error. Thanks for that. All is working now.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript has no namespaces, but they're commonly approximated with nested objects. If you want to split your functions among multiple files, each file must initialize the entire object hierarchy, *or* you need to guarantee the order of file inclusions in your page.

Typically it's better that each file initialize the object hierarchy so that you don't needlessly build cross-file dependencies:

#### file1.js

```
window.myAppFunctions = window.myAppFunctions || {}
window.myAppFunctions.ui = {}

window.myAppFunctions.ui.functionA = function () { /* ... */ }
```

#### file2.js

```
window.myAppFunctions = window.myAppFunctions || {}
window.myAppFunctions.db = {}

window.myAppFunctions.db.functionB = function () { /* ... */ }
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks for this, the first answer seems to be doing the job, but I see you are splitting functions into files? Allow me to add my comment/question I had on the first answer.

Comment: Regarding multiple name spaces and functions, Re, performance. Since scripts are "loaded", it seems to make sense to split different namespaces into different physical files, and only linking those you are going to use in the current page?

Comment: @LouisvanTonder Actually, this is the opposite of accepted best practices. In production, you should have a build process that minifies and concatenates all of your JavaScript files into a *single* long file, which is included on every page. There is no benefit to including some JavaScript in  one page and excluding others; the only real performance metric that matters is how quickly you can deliver all the necessary assets to the user, and it's far better to deliver a single minified gzipped JavaScript file *once* and have it cached than to include a different set of scripts on every page.