# Javascript, Array of Objects?

Tags: javascript, oop, jquery-mobile, mobile

I am a bit of a JS noob, but have good .net experience in my pocket.

I am working on a mobile website/app, and I have collected some data similar to business listings from a custom web service.

On .net, I would have, at this time, started building a custom class consisting of a list of other "business-listing-classes". I would then step through each custom object in my list, and use it on the screen.

Two questions:

- Should my javascript approach be different than above?
- Can this be done in Javascript?

I know javascript does not have classes persè, and I know you can have a custom function act as a "class". Am I then just to instantiate a bunch of different versions of said custom function, and add all of it to an array?

I almost have the feeling that I should just stick with them in the json format they are? Or build simple arrays? (From what I've learned from Javascript so far..)

Am I over engineering this? I am not sure what the correct javascript approach is.

Comment: I'm not sure where you read that *javascript does not have classes*.  You should read some more. This is a good reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Comment: Ahh thanks, maybe not in the sense that I am used to it on a .net platform? I was referring to this question I posted. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28697390/javascript-class-hierarchy-is-there-such-a-thing

Comment: JavaScript has no class, @Louis is right. JS has prototype inheritance. And object oriented does not mean classes.

Comment: Even though JS does not have *class* statement, it uses functions as classes. Yes, it's different from the other Class-based object-oriented languages in this sense.

Comment: Thus, I'd not say that JS has no classes.

Comment: @Yellen , agreed, as in my post: _I know javascript does not have classes persè, and I know you can have a custom function act as a "class". Am I then just to instantiate a bunch of different versions of said custom function, and add all of it to an array?_

Comment: EcmaScript 5 (current) does not have classes. EcmaScript 6 (soon) will.

Comment: No one to venture on an answer as to what the actual "right" js approach would be for this scenario?

Comment: I would suggest trying the TypeScript considering you are a .NET programmer. The TypeScript compiler gives out very good designed JS code. And VS even has a instant preview of compiled JS code. You can easily find how to write JS code to represent those OO concepts: class, interface, etc.

Comment: @LouisvanTonder - You'd be getting the data as JSON, right?

Comment: Well I would, and I am :-) Even in ES6, which introduce the `class` statement, there will be *no class*, and under the hood, it will still be prototype inheritance. It will only be syntactic sugar. You can invoke functions *as constructors*, yes, but that does not make it a class, with a 'contract'. In JS, objects are instantiated from objects (from functions, which are objects), not classes.

Comment: @LouisvanTonder don't over complicate JS code. Maybe you should try and show us what you coded and post it here.

Comment: @laruiss - Agree. But check ExtJs: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/core_concepts/classes.html :)

Comment: @Yellen Hehe, I know at least a dozen of Java-class-like implementations in JavaScript, from the [John Resig's April fools joke](http://ejohn.org/blog/classy-query/) one to the maybe more serious one from [javascriptMVC](http://static.javascriptmvc.com), and of course the [prototype](http://prototypejs.org/learn/class-inheritance) one, to point to a few. Needless to say, I am not fond of any. Still, Louis is right saying that "JavaScript does not have classes per se".

Comment: @laruiss - Yes, I'd agree to the statement. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It honestly depends what you want to do with this `array`

If you are going to send it via an `XMLHTTPRequest` then I'd say you should use `JSON` format.

```
var arr_of_objs = [{},{}]; //fill it up however you need it
```

If this array is going to consist of objects with the same `attributes/properties` and you were going to use this **client side**, creating *"classes"* is optimal.

```
var person = function(o){
  this.name = o.name || 'unknown';
  this.height = o.age || -1;
}
var arr_of_classes = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  arr_of_classes.push(new person({
    name: 'name' + i,
    age: 10 + i
  }));
}
```

Why stop there? You could even create a custom class to handle instances.

```
    (function(){
      var person = function(o){
        this.name = o.name || 'unknown';
        this.height = o.age || -1;
      }
      var personHandler = function(){
        if(!(this instanceof personHandler)){
          return new personHandler();
        }
        this.persons = [];
      }
      personHandler.fn = personHandler.prototype = {
        load: function(){
          for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            this.persons.push(new person({
              name: 'name' + i,
              age: 10 + i
            }));
          }
        },
        remove: function(index){
          //do stuff
        }

      }

   //export it
   window.personHandler = personHandler;

    })();
```

Then you would simply.

```
personHandler().load();
```